# Is there a way to link or export Visual Studio javascript breakpoints to Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, google-chrome, breakpoints

In VS i can set breakpoints on javascript code, which are correctly interpreted while debugging with IE.

Is there a way to do this with Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+i) in Chrome to debug JavaScript code. See the Scripts tab.

Comment: sure, but i have to re-set the breakpoints every time, right ?

Comment: it should remember the breakpoint. that's the point of having breakpoints, no?

Comment: actually i was wrong, you cant set a breakpoint inside VS for client side code.